# VS 2012 - Comparing dates between tables to control progression of package steps

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I've created an SSIS package that pulls data from various sources and aggregates it as needed for the business.  The goal of this processing is to create a single table, for example "Data_Tableau".  This table is the datasource for connected Tableau dashboards.

The Tableau dashboards need to be available during the processing, so I don't truncate "Data_Tableau" and re-populate with the SSIS package.  Instead, the SSIS package steps create "Data_Stage".  Then the final step of the package is a drop/rename, wherein I drop "Data_Tableau" and sp_rename "Data_Stage" to "Data_Tableau".

> USE dbname
>   DROP TABLE Data_Tableau
>   EXEC sp_rename Data_Stage, Data_Tableau

Before this final step, I expect  max(buydate) from "Data_Stage" to be greater than max(buydate) from "Data_Tableau", since "Data_Stage" would have additional records since the last time the process ran.
However, sometimes there are issues with upstream data and I end up with max(buydate) from "Data_Stage" = max(buydate) from "Data_Tableau".  In such cases, I would not want the final drop/rename process to run.  Instead, I want the job to fail and I'll send an alert to the appropriate upstream data team when I get the failure notification.

That's the long-winded background.  **My question is**...how do I check the dates and cause a failure within the SSIS package.  I'm using VS 2012.

I was thinking of creating a constraint before the final drop/rename step, but I haven't created variables or expressions before and am unsure how to achieve this.

I was also considering creating a 2-row table as follows:

> SELECT MAX(buydate) 'MaxDate', 'Tableau' 'FieldType' FROM dbname.dbo.Data_Tableau
>   UNION ALL
>   SELECT MAX(buydate) 'MaxDate', 'Stage' 'FieldType' FROM dbname.dbo.Data_Stage

and then using a query against that table as some sort of constraint, but not sure if that makes any sense and/or is better than the option of creating variables/expressions.

**Goal:** If MAX(buydate) from "Data_Stage" > MAX(buydate) from "Data_Tableau", then I'd want the drop/rename step to run, otherwise it should fail and "Data_Tableau" will contain the same data as before the package ran.

Suggestions?  Step-by-step instrux would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this by putting this:

> Then the final step of the package is a drop/rename, wherein I drop
>   "Data_Tableau" and sp_rename "Data_Stage" to "Data_Tableau".

into a stored procedure that gets called by the SSIS package.

Then it's simply a matter of using an `IF` block before that part of the code:

```
--psuedocode
IF (SELECT MaxBuyDateFromTableA) >= (SELECT MaxBuyDateFromTableB)
  BEGIN
  DROP TABLE Data_Tableau
  EXEC sp_rename Data_Stage, Data_Tableau
  END
ELSE
  --do something else (or nothing at all)
```